# Massachusetts Gas Dryer flex supply line

Tags: code-compliance, dryer, gas

I have a licensed plumber appt set next week to replace my gas dryer flex supply line with a longer line. Presently it has a 48" flex line but it restricts access needed by a drain company to snake my washer drain. My wash/dryer are a stackable set positioned next to a furnace. After speaking to a couple of plumbers on what is the maximum length the dryer gas flex line code compliance is. I received two different answers,one states 48" max and the other states 72" max. What is the correct maximum code length in Massachusetts for a condominium gas dryer flex supply line?

Comment: Your local building department / code enforcement officer has the info you need. Go Pats.